# 25th quantile for each column of a data frame in R

Tags: r

I am trying to iterate over a data frame in R. For each column I would like to print the 25th quantile.

Using data from the nycflights13 package I am trying the following:

```
abt <- select(flights, sched_dep_time)

for(i in names(abt)) {
  qrt_1 <- quantile(abt[i], c(.25))
  print(qrt_1)
}
```

However this gives me the error: Error: `Must use a vector in`[`, not an object of class matrix.`

Where am I taking a wrong turn here?

Comment: In your example you are using `select` to choose a single column from the `flights` data frame, which returns a `tibble` with a single column giving scheduled departure times. What do you mean that you are iterating over the data frame? If you want to iterate over flights you need to do `for(i in names(flights)) { if(is.numeric(flights[[i]])) {qrt_1 <- quantile(flights[[i]], c(.25), na.rm = TRUE); print(qrt_1)}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you are using `select` to choose a single column from the "flights" data frame, which returns a `tibble` with a single column giving scheduled departure times. You are not iterating over the data frame.

If you want to iterate over the flights data frame you need to do something like this:

```
cat("25th Quantiles:\n===============\n")

for(i in names(flights)) 
{ 
  if(is.numeric(flights[[i]])) 
  {
    qrt_1 <- quantile(flights[[i]], c(.25), na.rm = TRUE)
    cat(i, ":", qrt_1, "\n")
  }
}
```

Which prints the following to the console:

```
#> 25th Quantiles:
#> ===============
#> year : 2013 
#> month : 4 
#> day : 8 
#> dep_time : 907 
#> sched_dep_time : 906 
#> dep_delay : -5 
#> arr_time : 1104 
#> sched_arr_time : 1124 
#> arr_delay : -17 
#> flight : 553 
#> air_time : 82 
#> distance : 502 
#> hour : 9 
#> minute : 8
```

Comment: Could you explain the differnece between flights[i] and flights[[i]]. Both seem to work it seems.

Comment: @RuudVerhoef `flights[i]` in this context will be equivalent to `flights["year"]` (in the first cycle of the loop). The single brackets with a quoted column name give you a single-column data frame (or tibble). The double brackets give you the underlying _vector_ . This has some important differences. Check, for example the difference between `length(flights["year"])` and `length(flights[["year"]])`

Comment: is it also possible to store only the value returned by quantile() in qrt_1?

Comment: @RuudVerhoef yes. Before your loop do `qrt_1 <- list()`, and within the loop instead of writing to `qrt_1`, write to `qrt_1[i]`. This will put all the elements into a named list. You can then access these like : `qrt_1$year`

Answer (score 2):

This might not bring you a solution to your question why it does not work, but i want to present you an alternative with `lapply()`

```
lapply(mtcars, function (x) quantile(x, 0.25))
```

This also returns you the 25% quantile of every column in your dataframe. But every column must be numeric (which you assume in your example).

Also you can use `sapply` instead of `lapply` if you want a vectorised output

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe with dplyr's `summarise_if` (@emilliman5's comment):

```
library(tidyverse)

flights %>% 
  summarise_if(is.numeric, quantile, 0.25)
```

As you dindn't provide any reproducible example, you can check with `iris` data:

---

using `summarise_if`

```
iris %>% 
   summarise_if(is.numeric, quantile, 0.25)

#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#1          5.1         2.8          1.6         0.3
```

---

or using `sapply` and `select_if` (original answer):

```
iris %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  sapply(quantile, 0.25)

#Sepal.Length.25%  Sepal.Width.25% Petal.Length.25%  Petal.Width.25% 
#             5.1              2.8              1.6              0.3
```

Comment: You could simplify this further and use `summarise_if`